# Copying C-Style String to Free Store Using Only Dereference

Tags: c++, c, pointers, heap-memory

As said in the title, the goal is to copy a C-style string into memory without using any standard library functions or subscripting.

Here is what I have so far [SOLVED]

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

char* strdup(const char* p)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p[count]) ++count;
    char* q = new char[count+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; ++i) *(q + i) = *(p + i);
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = "Happy";

    char* heap_str = strdup(word);
}
```

Obviously the problem is that allocating just `*p` (which is equivalent to `p[0]`) only allocates the letter `"H"` to memory. I'm not sure how to go about allocating the C-style string without subscripting or STL functions.

Comment: Why no use of library functions or subscripting?  The library functions you'd use (strlen(), strcpy() and/or memcpy()) all have very, very simple naive implementations. Surely if you're not allowed to use them (a homework assignment?) it would be very easy to work up your own impementations.

Comment: It's an exercise from book I'm self-teaching.

Comment: It's a book I'm self-learning from. I'm fiddling with pointer arithmetic to deal with the subscripting.

Comment: You're not returned anything from your function AND you're not deallocated your dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: And like I said in my answer, you need to allocate length+1 because you need space for the null character as well.

Comment: The return part is for later as well as the deallocation. Chill, it's an exercise. I'll fix the allocation so it will have enough space for the terminating character.

Comment: Oh, I'm chilled. Just making sure you knew. :)

Comment: Oh yes, you need to copy the null character as well, so in the above example, you'd need to go from i=0 to i<=count.

Comment: Oops. I actually did i < count+1 just so it would be more readable (in comparison with the memory allocation of count +1) but yeah forgot to edit that in.

Comment: @trikker: If your book is a C++ book, this topic should either be far towards the end (when you have learned enough to understand it) or you should get a better one. I cannot remember when I have written such code for the last time, but it must have been one of the many string classes we used to write In The Old Times(TM) -- and that was ~10 years ago! Today we have `std::string` and `std::vector` for that kind of tasks. I'd kill anyone who would checkin code like that now.

Comment: The point is to learn about how pointers work and get some experience working low level. It is explained that there are much better facilities for performing such tasks, but someone had to write those facilities and we should understand how they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C-style string ends with '\0'. You need to traverse the string inside the function character by character until you encounter '\0' to know how long it is. (This is effectively what you would do by calling strlen() to work it out.) Once you know how long the string is, you can allocate the right amount of memory, which is the length+1 (because of the '\0').

To access the i'th element of an array p, one use subscript: `p[i]`.

Subscript of the form `p[i]` is formally defined to be `*((p)+(i))` by both the C standard (6.5.2.1 of C99) and the C++ standard (5.2.1 of C99). Here, one of `p` or `i` is of the type pointer to T, and the other is of integral type (or enumeration in C++). Because array name is converted automatically (in most types of use anyway) to a pointer to the first element of said array, `p[i]` is thus the i'th element of array p.

And just like basic arithmetic, `((p)+(i))` is equivalent to `((i)+(p))` in pointer arithmetic. This mean `*((p)+(i))` is equivalent to `*((i)+(p))`. Which also mean `p[i]` is equivalent to `i[p]`.

Comment: Now his only problem is to figure out how to do this without using `[]`. Good exercise.

Comment: Yes, I figured that I would need to know the string length, but even if I'm able to allocate the right amount of memory I still need to put the string in the memory. If I knew the string length this is what I would do: for(int i = 0; i < stringlength-1; ++i) q[i] = p[i]; but I can't use subscripting...

Comment: @KTC: Is it time to tell him about the i[p] exploit? :D

Comment: That's not really an exploit that is just part of the syntax. I couldn't use subscripting anyway and I can't see any real reason to use an i[p] format over a p[i] format unless you feel like confusing people.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since this a self-teaching exercise, here's an alternative look at a solution that can be compared/contrasted with KTC's nice explanation of the equivalence between subscripting and pointer arithmetic.

The problem appears to be, "implement a `strdup()` function without using standard library facilities or subscripting".

I'm going to make an exception for `malloc()`, as there's no reasonable way to do the above without it, and I think that using it isn't detrimental to what's being taught.

First, let's do a basic implementation of `strdup()`, calling functions that are similar to the ones we might use from the library:

```
size_t myStrlen( char* s);
void myStrcpy( char* dst, char* src);

char* strdup( char* p)
{
    size_t len = myStrlen( p);

    char* dup = (char*) malloc( len + 1);   /* include space for the termination character */

    if (dup) {
        myStrcpy( dup, p);
    }

    return dup;
}
```

Now lets implement the worker functions without subscripting:

```
size_t myStrlen( char* s)
{
    size_t len = 0;

    while (*s != '\0') {  /* when s points to a '\0' character, we're at the end of the string */
        len += 1;

        s += 1; /* move the pointer to the next character */
    }

    return len;
}


void myStrcpy( char* dst, char* src)
{
    while (*src != '\0') {  /* when src points to a '\0' character, we're at the end of the string */
        *dst = *src;

        ++dst;  /* move both pointers to next character location */
        ++src;
    }

    *dst = '\0'; /* make sure the destination string is properly terminated */
}
```

And there you have it. I think this satisfies the condition of the assignment and shows how pointers can be manipulated to move though an array of data items instead of using subscripting. Of course, the logic for the `myStrlen()` and `myStrcpy()` routines can be moved inline if desired, and more idiomatic expressions where the pointer increment can happen in the expression that copies the data can be used (but I think that's more confusing for beginners).